# Ionic/AngularJS/Phonegap Keyboard issue with iOS

Tags: cordova, keyboard, phonegap-build, ionic-framework

We created an app using Ionic Framework, AngularJS, Phonegap Build 3.4

We are having some keyboard issues with iOS - on Android its fine:

ANDROID:

Picture 1: We open a message that we received - the reply bar is in the ion-footer-bar div

[image: picture]

Picture 2: We tap on the write a message reply input box - this is correct:

[image]

iOS:

Picture 1: We open a message that we received - the reply bar is in the ion-footer-bar div

[image]

Picture 2: We tap on the write a message reply input box - this is NOT CORRECT! As you can see the whole screen shifted up and away when they keyboard is up. How can we fix this?

[image]

Comment: Same my issue in IOS 7. I not find solution.

Comment: Are you also using Phonegap Build? Or what are you using to build your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved this finally!! Firstly we had to add this to the ion-footer-bar:

```
  keyboard-attach
```

And then we upgraded Ionic to the latest stable release:

```
  1.0.0-beta.11
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the issue related to iOS 7.1 because our build was working fine on iOS. One plain hack could be to use [ionic keyboard plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard).

You see there are two events provided by this plugins

> 

```
native.keyboardshow
```

> ```
>     A number keyboardHeight is given on the event object, which is the pixel height of the keyboard.
>
> `native.keyboardhide`
> ```

keyboardHeight is sent whenever keyboard appears. You can use this height to resize your main content.

I know this is poor way of solving this issue but it can solve your problem until this issue is solved in framework.

Comment: Are you also using Phonegap Build? Or do you think its an Ionic issue? Or what are you using to build your app? I'm trying to isolate the problem..